# How to create a Facebook page without a personal account

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

In the past, Facebook used to let business create pages or apps without a personal account. This account created in the page/app creation process had limited capacities and could be switch to a full personal account after—if needed (irreversible).

But today, if I want to create a page for a new brand, without having a Facebook account, it seems I can’t anymore. And I can’t find any communication from Facebook regarding this change.

Anybody has any info? Is it still possible (in a new way maybe)?

Answer (score 3):

You can still use this option by making first you profile and converting it to a page. Read this https://www.facebook.com/help/www/116067818477568 otherwise go and create your page by migrating it to a page here https://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php?migrate . Notice the little yellow notifier on top of the page to learn more about "Profile To Business Page Migration". This is the only solution you can do right now on Facebook. By this way you will have only a page not a profile for your business.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatly the migration process failed in all the cases and forever. I'm required to ask the migration from a computer I used to use usually. And I got only one so ...